# what can cause a PHP session to fail on the first login attempt?

Tags: php, session

My script creates a new PHP session and immediately redirects the user to another page.

This works perfectly every time except for the first time after the server has been idle for an hour or so. On the second attempt and after that it works perfectly again. After the server has been idle it always fails, and after the first attempt it always works.

**Edit**
When the server has been idle, the session does not work. Everything works fine after that.

Theoretically, what could cause the session to fail on the first attempt like this?

I don't want to post any code here because there's simply because I don't know which part of the code to post. This is on IIS 7 with PHP 5.3. Same result both using CGI and FastCGI.

**Edit**
session_start(); is called on both scripts. The user will not see the first page as it redirects immediately to the next page. There's less than a second between the scripts.

Comment: I would have to say it's a coding/logic error and can't really be answered without seeing the code - a lot of guesses could be made though.

Comment: When you say "*the server has been idle for an hour or so*", does this mean you load the web-page in a browser and let it sit for *an hour or so* before attempting to log in?

Comment: I'm with @newfurniturey: show some code, my first guess would be that you're trying to access the `$_SESSION` super-global but your session has expired. Show some code, and tell us what you've tried

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are stored on disk. Your server's disk may be spinning down because of no activity. Then your script times out before the disk finishes spinning up. Possible?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that. Unfortunately It didn't solve the problem. I was thinking it could have something to do with not being able to write the session to the disk in time (the whole process is under a second)

Answer (score 1):

PHP sessions have a time out (if I understand your question correctly) which means they will "reset" after the timeout.

You can check the `session.gc_maxlifetime` in the php.ini file :)

If I didn't understand properly, then it might be an error in the code itself.

Comment: You can also use `php_value session.gc_maxlifetime` in your `htaccess` file if you don't want to edit the ini file on the server.

Comment: A session-timeout doesn't really make sense when applied to the OP's statement, in my opinion. He says that the first time the user tries to log in it doesn't work which would indicate the session is *new*; of course, I'm also confused by his "the server is idle" statement, so who knows.

Comment: __"This works perfectly every time except for the first time after the server has been idle for an hour or so"__ - it only fails on the first time AFTER the server has been idle. That quote is what led me to believe it could be an issue with timeouts.

Comment: @Prash still, he's talking about opening a session after 1h idle time, if it timed out, session_start() would just start a blank session and then, logic error in code could make it look like the thing failed. So you could be right but it is a little misleading in the current form

Answer (score 0):

> My script creates a new PHP session and immediately redirects the user to another page.

I interpreted your words to mean: Page 1 you're running `session_start()` and `header('Location: 'page2.php')` but on page2 it seems to me you're not doing `session_start()` again.

You need to session_start() on every page you will be using `$_SESSION`. In other words, place `session_start()` at the top of all your PHP pages or inside an include file you plan on running on every page.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. As it turns out it was caused by on old "feature" in one of the included modules. This "feature" was designed to end the session by calling session_destroy() if the session had been left open for over an hour.

This caused the problem that when the user tried to log in, PHP would notice an old session and call session_destroy(). After this everything seemed to be fine but no new session variables could be written to the session. There was no indication of a problem in the PHP log.

Changing session_destroy to session_unset solved the problem.